# Url parameter redirect

Tags: php, url

I don't know how to explain,what I want but from examples I think you know.
Momently my registration link is:

```
example.com/pages/registration.php
```

but I want to open my registration.php on this link:

```
example.com/registration
```

How can I do this? Or where can I learn about it,and how to call this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following redirection in .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /registration
RewriteRule ^registration ./pages/registration.php [L]
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking

Comment: Thx. I think is good. But how can I check in php if isset('registration')

? THx

Comment: we didnt pass anything then how come we check there if so you had to pass that in the query string.

Answer (score 1):

I know them as pretty URL's/clean URL's.

You can create them using a .htaccess file.

http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls

Comment: Thanks. It's nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using normal Header Redirect.

Open the file...

```
     `example.com/pages/registration.php`
```

At the top of that file simply add the lines:

```
<?php        
    header('location: example.com/registration');
    exit;
```